# Issue writing to spreadsheet using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm simply trying to edit a spreadsheet that has text already written into to change the text to be blank.

However it's not working. The method seems to do nothing.

My code is:

```
public static void ClearCells(string SpreadsheetFilePath)
{
    var SpreadsheetPath = new FileInfo(SpreadsheetFilePath);
    var package = new ExcelPackage(SpreadsheetPath);
    ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
    if (workBook != null)
    {
        if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
            currentWorksheet.SetValue(1, 1, "hello123");
        }
    }
}
```

There is no runtime error. It runs, completes and the spreadsheet is unchanged. I don't know why.

Comment: Which version of EPPlus library you are using ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call  `package.Save();` after you are done editing your file.

```
var SpreadsheetPath = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\abc.xlsx");
var package = new ExcelPackage(SpreadsheetPath);
ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
if (workBook != null)
{
    if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
        currentWorksheet.SetValue(1, 1, "hello123");
    }
}

package.Save();  // <========= MISSING IN YOUR CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static void ClearCells(string SpreadsheetFilePath)
{
    var excelFile = new FileInfo(SpreadsheetFilePath);
    var excelPack = ExcelPackage(excelFile);

    var workSheet = excelPack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content"); // New worksheet           
    workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "hello123";

    excelPack.Save();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using `SetCellValue` instead of `SetValue`?

```
public static void ClearCells(string SpreadsheetFilePath)
{

var SpreadsheetPath = new FileInfo(SpreadsheetFilePath);
var package = new ExcelPackage(SpreadsheetPath);
ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
if (workBook != null)
{
    if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
        currentWorksheet.SetCellValue(1, 1, "hello123");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seems like `SetCellValue()` is not available EPpLus version 3.1.3.0. Which version you are using ?